# How to use the values in a list to set new values in a dict?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dict:

```
inv = {"rope" : 1, "torch" : 6, "gold_coin" : 42, "dagger" : 1, "arrow" : 12}
```

and a list:

```
list = ["gold_coin", "dagger", "gold_coin", "gold_coin", "ruby"]
```

How do I write a function that uses the values in the list to set new values in the `inv` dict to get this:

```
inv = {"rope" : 1, "torch" : 6, "gold_coin" : 45, "dagger" : 2, "arrow" : 12, "ruby" : 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like that:

```
inv = {"rope" : 1, "torch" : 6, "gold_coin" : 42, "dagger" : 1, "arrow" : 12}
list = ["gold_coin", "dagger", "gold_coin", "gold_coin", "ruby"]
for elem in list:
    inv[elem] = inv.setdefault(elem, 0) + 1
```

> {'arrow': 12, 'dagger': 2, 'gold_coin': 45, 'rope': 1, 'ruby': 1, 'torch': 6}

NB: You sould not use keyword like list as variable name. Better variables name would be inv => inventory and list => items

## Explanations

We can separate you problem in several points:

1. Check if the item is present in the inventory.
2. If not, create a key in your inventory with a value equal to 0. (This is what **setdefault** does).
3. Increment the counter of the corresponding item.

So first we loop over the list of items to add with a for loop. Then we use the built-in method setdefault of dictionary. It takes the dict key to check and a default value to assign if the key doesn't exist, and return the value (default one or `inv[key]`). Finally we increment the item counter in the inventory by one.

### setdefault examples

```
inv.setdefault("rope", 0)
```

Does not create the "rope" key and returns 1 because the key already exists in the inv dictionary.

```
inv.setdefault("new_key", None)
```

Create the key "new_key" with None value and returns None because "new_key" doesn't exist in inv dictionary.

> inv
>   {"rope" : 1, "torch" : 6, "gold_coin" : 42, "dagger" : 1, "arrow" : 12, "new_key": None}`

Comment: Your answer works but try to explain the it a bit so that OP can understand.

Comment: That's right. I tried to add explanations. Sorry for the bad english.